# There is no 'Rigidbody2D' attached to the "Player" game object, but a script is trying to access it. (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to scripting in C# and I am trying to add a component to an object but I keep on getting this error:

> There is no 'Rigidbody2D' attached to the "Player" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

This is the code I have so far:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject.Find("Player");
    gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();        
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);
    Body.AddForce(movement * speed);
}
```

Comment: The error message explains it, your "player" object has no rigidbody..just select it, and add a rigidbody.

Comment: What is `gameObject`? Is it the same game object that your script is attached to?

Comment: @JoeSewell yeah, unity works like that. You can access the GameObject that the script is attached to using `gameObject` Similarly, Transform instance with `transform` etc

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş So `AddComponent` and `GetComponent` in the `Start` method should refer to the same game object?

Comment: Yes, and normally I would think this would work. but physics system might cause some other stuff to be set up. It is better to add components from the editor especially complex objects like rigid body or mesh or whatever. Also `GameObject.Find` at the beginning is doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

If you are adding script for the rigid body then you should attach a rigid body in the gameobject in the hierarchy view of the project . Click on the agmeobject in hierarchical view of the project . It will show you the inspector view of the gameobject and attach a rigid body to the gameobject and the error will be resolved and its helps us to implement the method of rigid body and physics regarding features .

[image]